# Retrieving data off my broken hard drive, what can I do?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

My Seagate Freeagent external hard drive broke the other day. I accidentally pulled on the chord with my leg and it fell on my desk. It then started beeping and was no longer recognizable by my laptop. I tried using different power supplies and USB cables, but nothing worked. Finally I removed the hard drive from the case (it wasn't under warranty) and it still didn't work, but it doesn't beep now, instead a white light is glowing.

I'm trying to get a different hard drive inclosure, but I really know nothing about hardware. I measured it and it's 5.5". Are there even inclosures made for that size? I called up multiple Best Buy's and everyone seemed confused when I told them the size, saying they only sold 'standard sizes'. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should do?

Well it's still connected to the SATA board, and the exact model is Seagate FreeAgent Desk 1.5 TB USB 2.0 Desktop External Hard Drive ST315005FDA2E1-RK.

Comment: The bare drive won't have any lights.  What's the exact model of the Freeagent?

Answer (score 2):

While the enclosure or length of the hard disk may be 5.5", the drive is most likely a 3.5" drive.  Measure the shortest length of the drive - the drive itself.

Your real question is whether you need a SATA or IDE based enclosure:

- If it looks like this it is SATA:

  [image]
- If it looks like this then it is IDE:

  [image]

From your description, you have only removed the case, you haven't fully removed the drive from the enclosure.  If you have something you can plug USB into still, then there is more to do to get it disconnected.  Usually it is clear what needs to be undone, but if you aren't sure, post a picture.

**Update** The original question has been updated with the drive info, and it looks like this must be a SATA 3.5" drive.  Any 3.5" sata enclosure should be suitable to drive this disk.

Comment: A picture would definitely help!